# Cannot change the maxrequest length in Azure VM IIS

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis

I am using Azure to run IIS which I host web site and then applications. I found that for the post controller to upload files. The maximum size is 4 mb. I have try to change web.config as follows:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="51200" enableVersionHeader="false" executionTimeout="3600" />

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

However, the max request length still can't be increased. I am doubting for Azure, there may be some other places to edit the max request length, or even it cannot be edited?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. It is not the limitation of Azure. It is because I did not add the file size limitation in the root web site web.config. I only edit in the lower level application's web config. Thus the whole site is still under 4mb size limit for upload. Finally, I edit the root web site's config and it worked now.

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.